# Set boolean to true if it's a certain number (or numbers) in a list of numbers

Tags: java, arrays

Basically I have a Boolean that I want to be true only if it equals one of the bad numbers in my fruit array. Here's what I'm trying to do:

The following is pseudocode:

```
public class fruitTypes {

public static int[] fruit = new int[10];
fruit[1], fruit[4], fruit[7] = rotten_fruit_numbers.

}

public class any_bad_fruit {

currentFruit = my_current_fruit;//loops through fruits i have

boolean has_bad_fruit = currentFruit == rotten_fruit_numbers; 
//this, i want to return true because some of the numbers are bad fruits.

}
```

The reason I'm trying this is because I'm trying to have an array of some sort of numbers in my static class. I may be better off with an enum, but is this logical and/or possible?

Comment: This is no valid, compilable java code.

Comment: Is **what** logical and/or possible? What are rotten_fruit_numbers? Also, why can't you iterate the `fruit` and test for rottenness?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I put some of your code in code blocks (the little {} button at the top does this). You may wish to clarify your title, which is slightly cryptic at a first glance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you exactly want, but try this(you can change arrays content):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] fruit = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int[] rotten = {17,3,23};
    System.out.println(isRotten(fruit,rotten)); // prints false or true, if array contains rotten ints
}

public static boolean isRotten(int[] fruit, int[] rotten){
    for(int part : fruit){
        for(int rottenPart : rotten){
            if(part == rottenPart) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question you are asking is "how can I create a function that determines whether any elements in a given array of integers is in another array of integers".

Here is an example of a solution:

```
private final int[] rottenFruit = {3, 7, 11}; // must be sorted

public boolean containsRottenFruit(int[] fruitArray) {
    return Arrays.stream(fruitArray)
        .anyMatch(fruit -> Arrays.binarySearch(rottenFruit, fruit) >= 0);
}
```

This uses Java 8 streams. An equivalent solution for previous versions would be:

```
public boolean containsRottenFruit(int[] fruitArray) {
    for (int fruit: fruitArray) {
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(rottenFruit, fruit) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```